# How do I update Firebase Analytics with google tag manager, that's already exist with google analytics along with Legacy google tag manager(GTM)

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My Android app analytics implemented with google analytics with legacy google tag manager with some user id dimensions, my query is how to update it with Firebase analytics with same user custom properties.

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarkOrmesher
Thanks for your advise, my question is, i have integrated google analystics with legacy GTM in my andorid app with some custom dimention like user id, but now as per google notice GA will be sunset soon, I am trying to update analystics with firebase, integration part is done and firebase default events are showing, my requirement is how do I update my custom events in firebase analystics and how to get the report for those evnets